# Excel and tab delimited files, using Carriage Return and Line Feed

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, newlines, carriage-return

How do you introduce a CR and LF into a cell so when it is saved as a Tab delimited text file, the importing program will recognize the CR and LF?

Answer (score 1):

You must use CRLF at the end of every row, and LF for carriage return inside a cell

[image]

In this way a spreadsheet will read properly the input

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ASCII character codes in the cell:

Line Feed `=CHAR(10)`

Carriage Return `=CHAR(13)`

If need be, copy and *paste values* to get rid of the formula.

Answer (score 0):

I use NotePad++ to edit the file after export.

View > Show Symbol > Show End of Line.

Then highlight the line break characters and do a find/replace (CTRL + h). [FYI: It only works for me when I highlight and not when I used the extended characters.]

In the 'Search Mode' section (bottom left of find/replace window) choose Extended.

Then in the 'Replace With' box put in what end-of-line character you want:

\r = Carriage Return = CR

\n = Line Feed = LF

\r\n = CRLF

For my needs, I replace CRLF with \n and then I replace LF with \r\n.
I have to do it in this order otherwise if I replace the LF first I get a CRCRLF; you may need to consider your order.

I'm trying to avoid this process with this question to make a batch file that does it for me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73225619/batch-script-to-replace-crlf-with-cr-then-lf-with-crlf-excel-to-timeslips-impo

Please upvote the question if it would help you.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party here, but if the goal is to introduce linebreaks into the original Excel file in such a way that they survive export to CVS and import back into Excel, use ALT+ENTER to add the linebreaks where required in the cell itself.

This automatically gives you the same result in the exported CSV as @aborruso has described.